# Create a "map" to fetch relevant data from various formatted Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a script that pulls in data from different locations, thus they are formatted differently, and then throws them into a list of "seen" items. We then poll periodically thereafter, checking if we've already seen it and if not, append it accordingly.

Given more resources may be added in the future I think it makes sense to create a generic script that accepts the pulled data and an accompanying map that describes the desired key against the data sets key.

```
/**
 * @param data
 *
 * Example:
 *  data: {
 *      0: {
 *          date: '2016-12-23 00:34:56',
 *          ...
 *          account: {
 *              name: 'name'
 *          }
 *      },
 *      1: {
 *          date: '...',
 *          ...
 *          account: {
 *              name: 'test'
 *          }
 *      }
 *  }
 *
 * @param map
 *
 * Example:
 *  map: {
 *      'username': 'account.name'
 *      // could have all sorts here
 *      // i.e. 'date': 'account.date_created'
 *  }
 *
 *  We only care about data[X].account.name and need to map this against our "global" identifier: username
 */
public process(data: any, map: any) {

    let seen: any = {}; // blank object

    // loop through each data object
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // data[i] = {date: '2016-12-23 00:34:56', ...}

        // loop through each key in the map
        for(let key in map) {

            // insert a new record
            // ie. seen = {username: 'name'}
            // ie. seen = {username: 'test'}
            // after looping, we get seen = {0: {username: 'name'}, 1: {username: 'test'}}

            seen = {[key] : data[i][map[key]]};

        }

    }

    // process list of seen objects

}
```

Unfortunately doing `seen = {[key] : data[i][map[key]];` simply returns `seen = {username: undefined}`. I've tried formatting the map so that the username key value reads `["account"]["name"]` but to no avail; it didn't work and not knowing any other way to access an object I'm now at a complete loss.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If so, how can I create a map that fetches the relevant data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because `account.name` is not a property of `data`, but `name` is a property of the nested object `account`. You could call `eval()`, which is not the best solution, or you could write a fairly simple parser function that solves the property accessor `.` notation, resolving each until the target property (in this case `name` of `account`) is reached.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dariusvs/sxjj3b97/

Comment: I ended up with something very similar but yes, recursion makes absolute sense. Thank you!